# Making one element fade out and a new element fade in with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a page that i'd let to use Jquery for navigating. When i click on a link, i want t a section to fade away and an new section, that i get with the get method to be inserted.

I've got this partially working, however, the fadeIn() method doesn't seem to work and i'm 100% sure how i should be going about doing this task.

this is the HTML of my index page

```
<div class="mid_section">
        <div class="home_content container">
            <div class="step_second_row">   
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="about.php" id="about_link">Learn more</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        something
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        something
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#about_link").on("click", function( e ){
        $(".home_content").fadeToggle("slow", function() {
            $.get("about.php", function( response ) {

                var content = $(response).find(".about_content");

                $(".mid_section").fadeIn("slow").html(content);
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The section being loaded

```
<h1>About us!!!</h1>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</p>
```

I'm really struggling with this, can anyone show me how to achieve this kind of thing? Or what i'm doing wrong, i am still in the process of learning Jquery as well.

thanks for your time.

Comment: did you get any error message in your console?

Comment: No errors at all, just one about preventDefault being deprecated, but that shouldn't have anything to do with it. (It's a bug in chrome i think)

Comment: @KristerAndersson That does the same thing, fades out then the new section just appears.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle please ?

Answer (score 2):

Try rhis:

```
$(".mid_section").html(content).hide().fadeIn("slow");
```

Loading content first and then fading would probably solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Do the ajax call first, that way it's likely finished when the element has faded out, and then just use the returned promise to catch the response and fade in the other element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#about_link").on("click", function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();

        var xhr = $.get("about.php");

        $(".home_content").fadeToggle("slow", function() {
            xhr.done(function(response) {
                var content = $(response).find(".about_content");
                $(".mid_section").hide().html(content).fadeIn("slow");
            });
        });

    });
});
```

Note that you're not fading in and out the same element ?

Answer (score 1):

For fadeIn to work the element must be hidden, in your case when the `fadeIn` is called the element is visible because you are fading out `home_content`.

Instead call `fadeOut` on `home_content`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#about_link").on("click", function (e) {
        $(".mid_section").fadeToggle("slow", function () {
            $(this).load('about.php .about_content', function () {
                $(this).fadeIn("slow")
            })
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Also use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the remote content

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#about_link").on("click", function( e ){
        $.get("about.php", function( response ) {
          $(".mid_section").fadeOut("slow", function() {


                var content = $(response).find(".about_content");

                $(".mid_section").html(content).fadeIn("slow");
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```